# Postfix + Dovecot Mail delivery permission problems

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

i've set up a postfix + dovecot mailserver on my linux 16.04 box.

Everything works fine, except for actually recieving the mail in my thunderbird client.

When I tail -f the mail.log, and send an email to my server, my server actually recieves the mail, passes it trough spamasassin, but seems to fail to deliver it correctly due to wrong permissions/usergroups.

Here's the mail.log line that I think is the problem

```
May 22 18:13:16 ed-w dovecot: lda(edward): Error: User initialization failed: Initializing mail storage from mail_location setting failed: mkdir(/var/mail/vmail//edward/mail) failed: Permission denied (euid=1000(edward) egid=1000(edward) missing +w perm: /var/mail/vmail/, dir owned by 5000:5000 mode=0755)
```

I'm hoping someone can help me out on setting the correct permissions or usergroups so that the mail can actually be delivered.

Comment: what permissions is `/var/mail/vmail/` ? `ls -lsd /var/mail/vmail/`

Comment: Hi mike, the output i get is : 
4 drwxr-xr-x 6 vmail vmail 4096 Apr  9 19:28 /var/mail/vmail

Comment: Bumping this question

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that the user edward with UID and GID 1000 is the one trying to perform the action, not the vmail user with UID and GID 5000.  You need to ensure that all services that dovecot are performing are running as the vmail user, and no other user.

In the future, posting a results of the command `dovecot -n` will help get you faster results so we can see your current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Mail users must be members of the vmail group. So after

```
usermod -a -G vmail edward
```

it should work.